# I'm having some problems with html select element, html buttons and html websocket connections

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket, computercraft

`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style>
        .custom {max-width: 24%; margin-top: 120px; line-height:200%; float: left;}
        .compid {width: 10%;float: right;font-size:80%;background-color:blueviolet;color:aliceblue;}
        button.compid {width: 10%;float: right;font-size:90%}
        .button {background-color: #04AA6D;border: 1px solid green;color: white;padding: 10px 24px;cursor: pointer;width: 50%;display: block;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;}
        .left {background-color: #04AA6D; border: 1px solid green; color: white; padding: 10px 24px; cursor: pointer; width: 25%; display: block; float: left; position: relative; left: 25.2%;}
        .right {background-color: #04AA6D; border: 1px solid green; color: white; padding: 10px 24px; cursor: pointer; width: 25%; display: block; float: left; position: relative; left: 24.7%;}
        #up {position: absolute; left: 25.4%; margin-top: 37px; width: 49.2%;}
        #down {position: absolute; left: 25.4%; width: 49.2%; margin-top: 74px;}
    </style>
    <body>
        <button onclick="inspect('down')">Inspect Down</button>
        <button onclick="inspect('up')">Inspect Up</button>
        <button onclick="inspect()">Inspect Forward</button>
        <button onclick="fuel('get')">Get Fuel</button>
        <p id="display">This Shows The Recieved Data</p>
        <button class="button" onclick="forward()">Forward</button>
        <button class="button" onclick="back()">Backward</button>
        <select id="comid" class="compid" onchange="selecte()"></select>
        <div><button class="left" onclick="left()">TurnLeft</button></div>
        <div><button class="right" onclick="right()">TurnRight</button></div>
        <button class="button" id="up" onclick="up()">Up</button>
        <button class="button" id="down" onclick="down()">Down</button>
        <textarea class="custom" id="cusinput" placeholder="turtle.forward()" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
        <button class="custom" onclick="custom()">Execute</button>
    </body>
    <script>
        var complist = [];
        var inselect = [];
        var channel = prompt("What server are you connecting to:", "2.tcp.ngrok.io:10546")
        let id = 0;
        if(!channel) {
            window.location.reload(true)
        }
        console.log(channel)
        const w = new WebSocket("ws://"+channel)
        w.addEventListener("open", () => {
            console.log("ok");
            w.send("WebClientConnected")
        });
        var snending = setInterval(function snend() {
            w.send('');
        },20000);
        w.addEventListener("message", (msg) => {
            console.log(msg.data)
            if(msg.data.substring(0,3) == "web") {
                document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = msg.data.substring(3);
            } else if(msg.data.substring(0,4) == "cweb") {
                if(complist) {
                    if(!complist.includes(msg.data.substring(4))) {
                        complist.push(msg.data.substring(4));
                        var opt = document.createElement('option');
                        opt.innerHTML = msg.data.substring(4);
                        document.getElementById('comid').appendChild(opt);
                        id = document.getElementById('comid').value;
                    }
                } else {
                    complist = msg.data.substring(4)
                }
                for (let x = 0; x < complist.length; ++x) {
                    console.log(complist[x].tostring);
                }
            } else if (msg.data.substring(0,4) == "rweb") {
                if (complist.includes(msg.data.substring(4)) & complist.indexOf(msg.data.substring(4)) > -1) {
                    var selectobject = document.getElementById("comid");
                    for (var i=0; i<selectobject.length; i++) {
                        if (selectobject.options[i].value == msg.data.substring(4)) {
                            selectobject.remove(i);
                            id = document.getElementById('comid').value;
                        }
                    }
                    complist.splice(complist.indexOf(msg.data.substring(4)),1);
                }
            }
            for (let e = 0; e < complist.length; ++e) {
                if (!inselect.includes(complist[e])) {
                    inselect.push(complist[e]);
                } else if (inselect.length > complist.length) {
                    if (!complist.includes[inselect[e]]) {
                        inselect.splice(inselect.indexOf(inselect[e]),1);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        w.addEventListener("close", () => {
            clearInterval(snending);
        });
        function selecte() {
            id = `comid ${document.getElementById('comid').value} `;
        }
        function up() {
            w.send(id+"up");
        };
        function down() {
            w.send(id+"down");
        };
        function left() {
            w.send(id+"left");
        };
        function right() {
            w.send(id+"right");
        };
        function forward() {
            w.send(id+"for");
        };
        function back() {
            w.send(id+"back");
        };
        function custom() {
            w.send(id+document.getElementById("cusinput").value);
        };
        function fuel(r) {
            if (r == "get") {
                w.send(id+"getfuel");
                document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Getting";
            }
        }
        function inspect(a) {
            if (a == "down") {
                w.send(id+"inspdown");
                document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Getting";
            } else if (a == "up") {
                w.send(id+"inspup");
                document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Getting";
            } else if (a != "up" & a != "down") {
                w.send(id+"insp");
                document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Getting";
            }
        };
    </script>
</html>
```

`

Focusing on the last few functions you'll see properly worded websocket send prompts, the issue being that either after the variable id has changed manually by the user or just the selected option in the select element changes by the user, the w.send command no longer sends anything and as far as I can tell it is only returning undefined.

I've tried a few ways around this yet none of them have worked so far, it's odd as this issue only seems to occur when sending a similar string with different information in the variable, through the web console I can send messages still, but only ones that aren't similar to the ones in the functions. I could be missing something obvious so I decided that asking about it here might be for the best. In case it's hard to tell what I'm trying to accomplish, I'm working with the cc: tweaked minecraft mod and making a connection to it via node js and an ngrok tcp server, on the web end I need to be able to take the list of computers I compile in the select element and select which option I'd like to send a message to. The most odd part though is that while it won't send messages if I interact with the select box, if the first select option disappears and a new one then is put into id it usually works without any issue. Also I'm sorry if this is an unpleasing read, it's my first time on stack overflow.

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: One second, I didn't notice the hyperlink, let me see if I actually can, though in the meantime I have this video better describing my predicament. https://vimeo.com/765790407 I'll also have to apologize for the quality of the video, used an older video software, had a bit of trouble with typing and took a bit to position for the demonstration. If you don't want to see any of the setup you can skip to about half way through and I'll start interacting with the website.

Comment: I have been able to create a small scale example to connect two html sites with a websocket, but I didn't run into the same error, I'll have to investigate it further but this complicates things. In any case I suppose that means that in a way the Minimal Reproducible Example allowed me to narrow it down to an issue specific to my program, I may be able to rewrite the entire thing and get it to work that way.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem, several errors were found in my websocket host. I happened to forget I'd arrayed my object that was used to collect the uuids soo I ended up sending a message that wouldn't get through the if statement and if it did it wouldn't actually send anything, sorry for the trouble.